# How do I put a picture on the right of my tex and type some tex on the left?

Tags: graphics

Sorry if I fail to make myself clear. To be specific, I want to make my pdf look like this.[image]

Comment: Use the `wrapfig` package.

Answer (score 1):

For example (your text replaced by `lipsum` and your image by an example image):

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}%
  \end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]